# Force EKS ENI worker node to have only 1 secondary private IP address?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am currently attempting to set up an EKS cluster with Node Groups that use a custom Launch Template. By default, EKS node groups have 2 ENIs attached. I need to configure my Cloudformation with a launch template for the node group to use in such a way that that one of those two ENIs only has ONLY 1 Secondary private IPv4 address. It's preferable that the primary ENI (device 0) would be the one to do this on.

Is what I am trying to do even possible? If so, what is the best approach?

I thought using the "secondaryprivateipaddresscount" value and setting it to 1 on the device index that I specified would do the trick but I get an error:

```
You cannot specify Private IP addresses in your launch template
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-launchtemplate-networkinterface.html#cfn-ec2-launchtemplate-networkinterface-secondaryprivateipaddresscount

I tried setting  `--max-pods=1` value in the user data to see what would happen and it does have 1 ENI with 1 secondary private IPv4 address but (as expected) it is only setting the total amount of pods on the entire node to be 1 which is not how I want this to work.